# Field of definition of a finite etale cover of an anabelian curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, anabelian-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be an anabelian curve over a number field $K$ and let $p:Y\rightarrow X$ be a finite etale cover. Then is anything known (or has anything been conjectured) about the field of definition of $Y$? In particular, should it be an abelian extension of $K$?

Comment: see the answer to my question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119981/are-all-anabelian-galois-actions-faithful which implies that you can get really awful extensions this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not, unless I totally misunderstand your question.  For instance, an unramified double cover of X is going to be defined over the field obtained by adjoining a 2-torsion point of the Jacobian of X, and that field is going to be non-abelian as all get out.